# How to avoid using doxygen's file command?

Tags: doxygen

Doxygen has a `\file` command, I had a look at different code bases and it seems some projects use it, some don't.

Having to maintain this adds some overhead *(needs to be corrected when splitting files up)* sometimes developers forget to do it.

Is there a way to infer this, eg: use the first doxygen formatted comment in the file as the `\file` comment.

Otherwise what is a good rule of thumb for when to use `\file` or not?

---

*Note, I tried removing this command from all files and the output changed to group information less usefully and the order of some information changed, so it does make a difference.*

Comment: You can use the `\file` command without the file name, and the documentation block for it will be used for the file. That way you don't need to update the file name when you split files up. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Great, wasn't aware this was optional.